# Yii Framewok Foreign Key Store In The Database When Selected From Dropdown List

Tags: php, yii, rdbms

In [yii framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/) I am doing a small application. Where I have two tables in my database named as `products and sales`
 Product table is something like this

```
 ================
      product
   ================
   +   id          +
   + product_name  +
   + cost_price    +
   +selling_price  +
   + created_by    +
   + updated_by    +
   + created_at    +
   + updated_at    +
   +++++++++++++++++


   =================
          Sales
   =================
   + id            +
   + product_id     +
   + price          +
   + created_by    +
   + updated_by    +
   + created_at    +
   + updated_at    +
   +++++++++++++++++
```

For all the above two tables I have done the Models and controllers from gii tools(crud)
After that I just made relations in Sales model. The relation is like this

```
  public function relations()
  {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
      'product' => array(self::HAS_MANY,'Products','product_id'),
    );
  }
```

After that I just rendered the Products model in Sales model.
  Sales controller action create is something like this

```
 public function actionCreate()
  {
    $model=new Sales;
    $products = new Products;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Sales'], $_POST['Products']))
    {
      $model->attributes=$_POST['Sales'];
      $products->attributes = $_POST['Products'];
      $valid = $model->validate();
      $valid = $products->validate();

      if($valid)
      {
        $products->save(false);
        $model->product_id = $products->getPrimaryKey();
        $model->save(false);

        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
      }
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
      'model'=>$model,
      'products' =>$products,
    ));
  }
```

and in view I am rendering the files like this

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($products,'product_name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropdownList($products,'product_name', CHtml::listData(Products::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'product_name'), array('empty'=>array('choose'=>'---Select One---'))); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($products,'product_name'); ?>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'price'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'price'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'price'); ?>
  </div>
```

Here I am doing the dropdown list of all the available products from the products table. After that when I am doing save the total form.

The product_id inside sales table showing NULL. I want the foreignkey in that place when the selected product is selected from the dropdown. Kindly tell me where I am doing the wrong. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: When u select an item from dropdown what action do u want to do ??

Comment: @Ninad  I want to store the refernced key (foreign key) of product in the database.

Comment: Means when u select a product say ex:Iphone u want  its id to be stored in Db or id of the sales item to which this id is referenced ??

Comment: @Ninad as like ur example iPhone is stored in product table and when I am in sales form I am getting all the products in a dropdown list. Then when I will select the product its foreignkey which is in sales table will be store.

Comment: Simple is it like this when u select Iphone its id should be updated in the sales table product_id field ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33412/discussion-between-newuser-and-ninad)

Answer (score 0):

Do it something like this

```
<?php echo $form->dropdownList($products,'product_name', CHtml::listData(Products::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'product_name'), array('id'=>'productType','name'=>'productType'))); ?>
```

Your hidden variable

```
<?php echo CHtml::hiddenField('productTypeId','',array('class'=>'ProductTypeId')); ?>
```

And the javascript code to select the id

```
 $('#listingType').change(function(){
        var productid=$('#productType').val()
        $(".ProductTypeId").val(productid);
         });
```

In controller action

```
public function actionCreate(){
     $productId=$_POST['productTypeId'];
     //code to store in sales table 
}
```